# Python/Opencv - Display multiple video feeds in a single window

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am fairly new to opencv and am trying to do the following; display stream from 3 different cameras in a single window and save that stream as an avi. I have the following code for displaying 2 cameras but in two different windows. How could I concatenate these two windows into a single window then save that as an .avi?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = video_capture_1.read()

    if (ret0):
        cv2.imshow('camera 1', frame0)

    if (ret1):
        cv2.imshow('camera 2', frame1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture_0.release()
video_capture_1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I wanted to do this without threading if possible as I found a pretty significant delay between live and what was shown on stream. I feel like it should be a simple solution to just stitch 2 windows together but I can't figure it out.

Comment: numpy hstack/vstack. and **no**, if you have multiple cameras, they won't run in sync, so you have to deal with that (them running out of sync). that means running threads, reading frames as quickly as they are available, and then matching those...

Comment: So with my current code, 2 windows open up displaying 2 video feeds (laptop webcam and external camera). There isn't a noticeable delay and I am happy with the result. I just want to combine these 2 windows into a single window containing 2 different video streams. I have seen online about using cv2.hconcate but I haven't got that to work.